# Safetynet attestation request from a webview's javascript?

Tags: javascript, webview, safetynet, safetynet-api

Today I was wondering if it would be possible to perform a Safetynet attestation request from the webview of an app.
I actually would assume 'yes' because a webview lives in the context of an app and so it would be possible for the request to get the context of the app. (I haven't used Safetynet but I know that it send the package name and the app signature along with the request to asure app integrity. On the other hand I would assume the answer is 'no' because when I search 'safetynet webview' or 'safetynet javascript' I get zero relevant hits on google.